# In how many ways can we sign a checkerboard with the following conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have a checkerboard with 3 rows and 7 columns. In how many ways can we sign 6 squares on the board that every row will have 2 squared signed and every colums will have at most 1 square signed?

My calculation: $3*7 + 3*6 + 2*5 + 2*4 + 3 +2 = 62$

Can someone confirm or fix me if i'm wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Polymonos]

The problem can be reduced to counting the way to arrange the seven polyominos.

The six containing signed squares can be arranged in $6!$ ways, but for each arrangement $8$ are identical in appearance, so there are actually only $6!\div8=90$ distinguishable arrangements of the six.

The blank polyomino can occupy $7$ positions for each arrangement of the $6$ for a total of $90\times7=630$ arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for every row we have two signed squares, for the first row we have $21$ way to do that.

The first signed square is in the first column and the second could be on all remaining $6$ or the first signed square is in the second column and the second could be on all remaining $5$ and so on, so we've got $6+5+4+3+2+1=21$.

For the second row we have also $21$ (the same argument as row $1$ apply) but now we have a pair above (in row $1$ ) the we cant be in same column as above row, so when our signed square is in the same column as the signed square above we lose $6$ places from the $21$ and when we are in the same column as the other signed square we lose another $6$ but we gain $1$ were the two signed squares in the second row are in the same column as the first row because we counted it twice, thus leaving us with $10$ possible arrangements.

For the third row we have also $21$ (the same argument as row $1$ apply) and we lose 4-times $6$ (the same argument as row $2$ apply but now we have to deal with 4 previous signed square rather than $2$ and we gain $6$ because there are 4 signed square and there is 6 possible colliding pairs),thus leaving us with $3$ possible arrangements.

So in total there is $21*10*3 = 630$ valid arrangements.

Note :

1 0 1 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Here for example, i have to signed square in the same column, so it doesn't matter where will i put the fourth signed square, it will always be invalid and thus losing $6$ positions in the second row,(this what i was talking about in the answer in case if you did not fully understand the words).

also i checked it with computer program and it printed $630$ valid cases.

hope its what you are looking for.